# How do you print out the binary representation of a file?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a compression program but I need to know the basics of how to open a file in binary and print out its contents.

In a text file, called "Tester.txt", I have this:

> MJ

In a .cpp file, I have this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main
{ 
    fstream istr;
    istr.open("Tester.txt", ios::binary);      
}
```

From my understanding in the cplusplus reference, this uses a stream object to open the file specified in binary?

But I'm stuck on how exactly I can "print" out the first byte of the file, i.e. the letter M in binary?

I know that M (capital letter) in binary is 01001101.

So how do I do a cout of M in binary?

Thanks

Comment: cplusplus.com is short on explanation and verification. It appears first on Google because of dirty SEO tricks. Please don't click Google's links to cplusplus.com. Use cppreference.com instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick program which uses the C++ Standard Library to do all the heavy lifting.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <bitset>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::istreambuf_iterator< char > in( std::cin ), in_end;
    std::ostream_iterator< std::bitset< 8 > > out( std::cout, " " );
    std::copy( in, in_end, out );
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

[See it run.](http://ideone.com/lidsMS) I used `std::cin` for demonstration, but you should open a file with `std::ios::binary` and pass that instead.

Since each variable is only used once, this could all be done on one line. Even if you open the file instead of using `std::cin`.

---

**EDIT:**

- `std::copy` is a function encapsulating the loop `for ( ; in != in_end; ++ in ) * out ++ = * in;`.
- The type `std::istreambuf_iterator` either takes an `istream` constructor argument and provides an iterator `in` suitable for such a loop, or takes no constructor argument and provides an iterator `in_end` such that `in == in_end` if `in.eof() == true`. The iterator gets unformatted bytes (type `char`) from the stream.
- The type `std::ostream_iterator< std::bitset< 8 > >` provides an iterator `out` so `* out ++ = x` converts `x` to `std::bitset< 8 >` and prints the result. In this case `x` is a byte and `bitset` provides a constructor for such a byte value, and overloads `operator<<` to print a binary representation of 1's and 0's.

Comment: Thank you very much Potatoswatter! this was actually what I was looking for. I opened the Tester.txt file and passed it as the argument, and it printed out the binary representation of the letters in the file. I am trying to understand the code you wrote, but cppreference does not really help me. Can you explain to mean lines 7-9? What is each line doing? What "type" of parameter is passed into in(..)? What does in_end do? Where is the member function copy from? Thank you!

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu Cool, don't forget to click the up arrow and checkmark at the upper left corner of this answer.

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu Sorry I didn't see your whole comment message earlier. See update.

Comment: Is there a way to print in hex format with this technique?

Comment: @Daniel [here you go](https://ideone.com/ajiTNE)

Answer (score 3):

You have a confusion between numbers and representations of numbers, probably created by the fact that the word "binary" can sometimes be used to describe both. When you open a file in "binary mode", that means you see the raw values of the bytes in the file. This has *nothing* to do with "binary" in the sense of representing numbers in base two.

Say a file has "x" followed by a newline and a return. In "binary mode", you will see that as three byte-size values, one containing the ASCII code for "x", one containing the ASCII code for newline, and one containing the ASCII code for return. These are *values* that you read from the file. You *can* represent them in binary, but you can also represent them in decimal or hex, you still have read the exact same *values* from the file.

Reading a file in "binary" determines the *values* you read, not how you represent them. Two cars are the same two cars whether you *represent* the *value* two as "2" (decimal), "10" (binary), or "two" (English).

Comment: He may be confused or maybe not, but binary mode is appropriate for printing any binary representation, which seems to be what he wants. If you're going to mention line endings (which are the only real difference between text and binary mode), better to elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

Binary input/output on streams is done using their member functions `read()` and `write()`.

Like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main
{ 
    fstream istr;
    istr.open("Tester.txt", ios::binary);
    if (istr) {
      // Read one byte
      char byte;
      if (!istr.read(&byte, 1)) {
        // Error when reading
      }
      // Alternative way to read one byte (thanks to DyP)
      byte = istr.get();
      // Another alternative:
      if (!istr.get(byte)) {
        // Error when reading.
      }
      // Read a block of bytes:
      char buffer[1024];
      if (!istr.read(buffer, 1024)) {
        // Read error, or EOF reached before 1024 bytes were read.
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference to `get`? If there's none, it would be a bit simpler to get a single char/byte.

Comment: @DyP Thanks, added. I generally prefer `read()` and `write()` as sole binary accessors, but you're right that `get()` is unformatted as well.

Comment: As there's a C++11 tag, you could also use `std::array<char, 1024>` instead :P

Comment: @DyP Indeed; when typing quickly, old habits are hard to break ;-)

Comment: @Dyp - a file opened as binary is exactly the same as a normal file, with the one exception that the library will never translate line ends to the Unix-standard linefeed character. This only really affects Windows, and a lot of Unix-only developers ignore binary mode even when working with binary files (then wonder why things break when they end up having to deal with Windows). Personally, I use binary mode for everything including text if I'm reading a file - handling multi-platform line-ends is easy, but when the stream translates them for you you get position/size/offset confusion.

Comment: Which is why when reading into a buffer you would normally go `if (!istr.read(buffer, 1024) && istr.gcount() == 0) { /* ERROR */}`

Answer (score 1):

To output a value in binary you need to do it manually as the standard library does not support that output format.

```
int mask = 0x80;
while(mask)
{
    std::cout << (byteValue & mask ? '1' : '0');
    mask >>= 1;
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

This will scan from the top bit to the low bit and print out a value representing each one.

Comment: There are the stream manipulators `dec`, `hex` and `oct` for setting the output base for a stream, but there's no binary mode that I can see, so this is probably right for output as binary digits - except that I think the bit-shift is shifting the wrong way.

Comment: Oops - actually the bit-shift is correct, I'm just in the habit of shifting the value rather than the mask.

Comment: Don't do it manually. Use the tools you have: `std::bitset<8>(byteValue).to_string()` should work wonders.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <iomanip>


int main()
{ 
    // Set up your objects.
    char          c;
    std::fstream  istr("Tester.txt", ios::binary);  
    unsigned long loc = 0;

    // Read the file one character at a time.
    // Remembering not to skip white space in this situation.
    for(;istr >> std::noskipws >> c;++loc)
    {
        // When printing compensate for non printable characters.
        // If the character is outside the ASCII range then print it as an integer.
        std::stringstream  charStr;
        if ((c < 32) || (c > 126))
        {
            charStr << "Char: " << c;
        }
        else
        {
            charStr << "Non Printable: " << static_cast<int>(c);
        }

        // Print the value and location in a nicely formatted way.
        std::cout << std::setw(16) << location 
                  << " : " 
                  << std::bitset<8>(c).to_string()  // Prints the character as an 8 bit binary value.
                  << " : "
                  << charStr.str()
                  << "\n";
    }
}
```

But there are standard tools that do this already:

[Look at `od`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Od_%28Unix%29)

Comment: As `>>` behaves like a formatted input function, couldn't that raise problems with encoding/conversion?

Comment: `std::cout << charStr.rdbuf();` should also be possible (and possibly faster). You're missing a closing bracket in `if ((c < 32) || (c > 127)`. The Standard doesn't require the use of ASCII as basic execution character set. `127` == DEL is arguably printable.

Comment: @DyP: 1) No `operator>>` with char reads a char without interpretation. Fixed bug `c > 127))`. .rdbuf() faster?In this situation I doubt it (probably the same speed). Even if it is the difference is negligable.I also think .str() is more readable in this situation and thus more maintainable thus the prefered solution (but this is arguable). NO ASCII is not guranteed by C/C++ but now we are working with things outside the language (as it is the shell that determins how it is interpreted not the application). Correct std::isprint(0x7F) is false. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isprint/